# Spark job JAVA RDD performance all data goes to one executor node

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, rdd, jobs

I am having difficulty with a Spark job performance,most of the data is run by only one executor in the cluster even though there are many nodes available.

To elaborate the job logic,Basically we have two hbase table events and items,the spark job counts the number of events for some specific duration.First I read the events from events table and pass the results to the process,where it get the items for specefic events and then apply some business logic and then  does the count.

the job takes 8-10 mins for processing only 2000 rows wheres as the same job run in mapreduce process million rows for  the same time.
As I am very new to Spark ,I dont know whats wrong in the code.

Below is the code for reference

```
public class ABC{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args == null || args.length < 3) {
        System.out.println("Specify input parameters: <itemshdfspath>,  <datefrom> <dateto>");
        return;
    }

    String hbTable = "mevts";       
    String dateFrom = args[1];
    String dateTo = args[2];
    String itemsHdfsPath = args[0]; //hdfs path

    //Create a SparkContext to initialize
    SparkConf sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName(" events ");

    // Create a Java version of the Spark Context
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sconf);

    Processor.jsc = sc;
    Processor.hdfsPath = itemsHdfsPath;
    Processor.dateFrom=dateFrom;
    Processor.dateTo=dateTo;

    Configuration conf =HbaseConfiguration.get();
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, hbTable);
    String hdfsTarget = itemsHdfsPath ;          
    Path hdfsItemsOutputn = new Path(hdfsTarget);                       
    hdfsItemsOutputn.getFileSystem(conf).delete(hdfsItemsOutputn,true);  
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

    List<RowRange> ranges = new ArrayList<RowRange>();
    String[] prefixes = new String[] { "C", "D"};
    for (String prefix : prefixes)
        ranges.add(new RowRange(prefix + dateFrom, true, prefix + dateTo, false));  
    Filter eventsFilter = new MultiRowRangeFilter(ranges);
    scan.setFilter(eventsFilter);

    ClientProtos.Scan proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan);        
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, Base64.encodeBytes(proto.toByteArray()));

    JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> source = sc
            .newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
                    ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);

    Processor.process(source);
}
```

}

```
public class Processor {
public static JavaSparkContext jsc;
public static String hdfsPath;
public static String kbsKeyTabFilePath;
public static String kbsUser;
public static String dateFrom;
public static String dateTo;

public static void process(JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> source) {
    Broadcast<String[]> bcParams = jsc.broadcast(new String[] { hdfsPath, kbsKeyTabFilePath, kbsUser, dateFrom,
            dateTo });

    List<Tuple2<String, Long>> res = source
    .map(f -> Bytes.toString(f._2.getRow()))
    .mapPartitions(p -> {
        String[] params = bcParams.value();
        Configuration conf = params[1] == null ? HbaseConfiguration.get()
                :HbaseConfiguration.get(params[1], params[2]);
        HTable mailItemsTable = new HTable(conf, "");
        // RefDataCache refDataCache=RefDataCache.fromJson(params[7]);
        Iterable<String> iterable = () -> p;
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).map(s -> {
            try {
                String key = s.toString();
                long fromDatel = Long.parseLong(params[3]);
                long toDatel = Long.parseLong(params[4]);
                String EventName = key.substring(0, 2);             
                String itemID = key.toString().substring(14);
                Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(itemID));
                g.setMaxVersions(1);
                Result item = mailItemsTable.get(g);
                String itemId = Bytes.toString(item.getRow());
                List<Cell> getCOrDCells = item.listCells().stream()
                                                          .filter(c -> (Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(c)).substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase(EventName))
                                                                        && Long.parseLong(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(c)).substring(2))>=fromDatel 
                                                                        && Long.parseLong(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(c)).substring(2))<toDatel)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
                mailItemsTable.close();//
                if (getCOrDCells == null || getCOrDCells.size() < 1)
                    return null;
                String  eventName = null,eventcode = null;
                Cell getEarliestSendingEvent = getCOrDCells.get(0);
                eventName = Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(getEarliestSendingEvent));
                String evtDT = eventName.substring(2);              
                JSONObject evtObj = new JSONObject(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(getEarliestSendingEvent)));
                eventcode = eventName.substring(0, 2);
                String recipientId = evtObj.getString("r");
                String senderId = evtObj.getString("s");
                String senderOpeCode = senderId.substring(0, 2) + "A";
                String recipientOpeCode = recipientId.substring(0, 2) + "A";
                Item Item = new Item();
                Item.ItemID = itemId;
                Item.OrigOp = senderOpeCode;
                Item.DestOp = recipientOpeCode;
                if (eventcode.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                    Item.CDT = evtDT;
                else
                    Item.DDT = evtDT;
                if (Item == null)
                    return null;
                List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> colValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                Item.storeToHBase(colNames, colValues);
                StringBuilder valBuilders = new StringBuilder();
                for (int c = 0; c < colValues.size(); c++) {
                    if (c != 0)
                        valBuilders.append("\t");
                    valBuilders.append(colValues.get(c));
                }
                return valBuilders.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                return (String) null; // this will throw exception further
                                      // in spark
            }
        }).iterator();
    })
    .flatMapToPair(f -> {                 
        String itemDetails = f.toString();
        Item Item = new Item(itemDetails);
        List<Tuple2<String, Long>> listMap = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Long>>();
        if (isValid(Item.CDT))
            listMap.add(new Tuple2<>("CCount", 1L));
        else
            listMap.add(new Tuple2<>("DCount", 1L));
        return listMap.iterator();

    })
    .reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y).collect();

    for (Tuple2<String, Long> tpl : res) {
        System.out.println(tpl._1 + ": " + String.valueOf(tpl._2));
    }
}

public static boolean isValid(String val) {
    return (val != null && !val.isEmpty());
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong with the given code, how should we? What does not work as expected? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,the code above counts the number of events  and works as expected the problem is with the performance when it runs on the cluster ,it takes 10 mins to process 2000 rows in spark,where as the same logic when run on mapreduce process million rows .I  had checked that the most time is spent on flatmappair ,I am verifying that is there anything wrong in the way the RDDs are written and below is the  config  used, num of executors:36 driver memory:2g executor memory: 17gb executor cores: 5.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the question itself, not to the comment section